# Using of Array of chars (char[]) instead of strings in c#

Tags: c#, c, string, char

There is no such concept as string in C language, right? 
So, i'm wondering: would it give any memory saving advantages to use array of chars instead of string in modern languages, as C# for example.

Comment: In C a "string" is simply an array of characters terminated by a zero. So while it doesn't exists a specific `string` type, it does indeed have strings.

Comment: I doubt that, .NET run-time for string stores only characters + length of string (in IL strings are loaded using separate instruction `ldstr`, in other words they are not treated like classes). Same strings are represented by exactly same instance of string - this is called interning (memory savings here). You can only save memory when you are constantly modify strings (they are immutable by default) - but in that case there is StringBuilder that internally uses char[]

Comment: A string is a class that consists of characters.  The methods in the string class are different from the methods in the character class.  So a string and a character are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, if I'm understanding you correctly, the answer is "it depends". (I'm using python out of convenience, you said "any modern language")

I made a function that creates a character array of the alphabet, and another that creates a string of the alphabet. Then ran them each 1 million times.

The character array took about 1.7 seconds, compared to the string array's .5 seconds.

"Maybe it's an overhead thing?" you might ask.
Fine: I initialized them globally, then ran an iteration of each one through a loop (1 million times), setting some variable to the current letter.
7.7 seconds for the character array vs 9 seconds for the string.

"What if you're looking for a particular element?"
I ran through each variable to see if 'z' was in the elements. char array took 1.8 seconds vs the strings 0.4 seconds.

"That's interesting, maybe it's just an assignment thing?"
My last test is to just iterate through without assigning anything.
Again, the char array is faster with 3.9 seconds vs the 5.3 seconds of the string iteration.

So it seems that Strings are faster for initial creation and searching (I also assume sorting, but I'm not about to write a sorting function to find out), while character arrays are faster for iterative events (for each in array/string).

Hope this helps.
PS - the code for my first test class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dis
import time

def char_func():
        my_c_var = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        #print my_c_var

def stri_func():
        my_s_var = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        #print my_s_var

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
        char_func()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
        stri_func()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```